# My Travis-CI integration with GitHub was break down

Tags: github, travis-ci

My Travis-CI integration with GitHub was break down

I have a simple [python flask project](https://github.com/yn-coder/CodingTeacher/commits/master) on GitHub with PyTest tests and Travis-CI integration.

Few days ago (26 of september) building autotests by commit was down. No integration settings was changed, only some code.

[image: 26 sept travis is ok]

Can Travis could be down, or what could be wrong?

**UPDATE**

Repo settings:

Travis is green marked, but I see `Note: GitHub Services are being deprecated. Please contact your integrator for more information on how to migrate or replace a service with webhooks or GitHub Apps.` message.

[image]

Comment: Did you change something on GitHub's side? Could you check if this repo still has a user with Admin access?

Comment: Nothing is changed in settings

Comment: Could you check if Travis CI is properly enabled on GitHub here: https://github.com/yn-coder/CodingTeacher/settings/installations ? You should see a green checkmark and `Active` should be checked if you click on the `Edit` button.

Comment: @DominicJodoin I've add a screen to repo settings. Travis have a green mark in settings and in Edit page.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it.
As I've seen, Travis is got the signal from GH commit and rebuilds the tests each time, but GH is not retrieve the complete/fail signal back.

I think it's because GitHub Services is deprecated.

I remove the GH repo link to Travis and relink it again. Now it's a WebHook and working well.

Comment: Looks like there is now a GitHub App for Travis, which you can sign up for by moving from www.travis-ci.org to www.travis-ci.com